# Count if column is duplicating

Tags: php, mysql

Consider the following table

**Entry Date     UserID**
  2012-15-03      4

2012-15-03      4

2012-15-03      3

2012-15-03      1

I want to count the useID field ,if userID appearing more than once in database....
The result I expected 
count =2(that means 4 is repeating twice)
Please let me knothe mysql query for fetching the above requirement with one query

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `GROUP BY` with `HAVING` clause to get the duplicate ones, something like

```
SELECT ... FROM ... GROUP BY ... HAVING ...
```

What you need to put instead of ... is very simple.  Do a bit of research, read basic mysql documentation and you'll be able to get this done very easily.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to count all records then:

```
SELECT userID, COUNT(*) FROM table GROUP BY userID
```

if you want a list of duplicates use:

```
SELECT userID, COUNT(*) FROM table GROUP BY userID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: While this may be helpful for the immediate question at hand, unfortunately it will do nothing to help the OP learn. People coming here saying "do this for me" isn't the right approach on this forum. And by actually doing what they ask you are only encouraging such behaviour.

Comment: As much as I agree with your stance - and for the most part agree with it, the only response to any MySQL question would be to link the MySQL docs - or inform them to buy a MySQL book written by someone. My reaction when given - or searching for a solution would be then to understand it - if they are not prepared to learn like that then they are not going to learn ever.

Comment: I disagree.  I'm not against providing a solution to somebody who tried to do something, struggled and eventually came for help.  I am absolutely against providing solution to somebody who couldn't bother to try anything for themselves and just want others to do the job. [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT entry_date, userid, count(1) as Total
FROM myTable
GROUP BY userid
HAVING Total >=2
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/70e6a/7)